# how to get parameter in other class

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my first class:

```
public class IntelliChart
{
        string _chartName;
        public IntelliChart(string chartName)
        {
            _chartName = chartName;
            _chartParamProvider = new ChartParameterProvider();
            _userBLL = new UserBLL();
            _factormasterBll = new HealthFactorMasterBLL();
        }
}
```

Below is my second class:

```
internal class DefaultAllReadingsDataProvider : DataProvider
 {
    internal override OutputData GetOutputData(Guid userId, int N, int pageNum)
        {

        }
 }
```

Now in the above code i want to get _chartName in second class. i try session, viewstate and also create global variable but its not working.

Comment: Please read about [Access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Comment: it means its not possible?

Comment: Make that public string _chartName

Comment: Your variable is private, which means it can only be accessed from code in the same class

Comment: still not working, please tell me what do i do to get it

Comment: Have you created an object of IntelliChart class in your second class ?

Comment: yes but when i create it, it throws me error

Comment: Perhaps a good book on _C# 101_ as SO is not really a site to _teach_ you how to program

Comment: so what do i do here, do i change the class or its modifier ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try in that way:-

In first class:-

```
public string _chartName;
```

In Second Class:-

```
    internal class DefaultAllReadingsDataProvider : DataProvider
         {
            internal override OutputData GetOutputData(Guid userId, int N, int pageNum)
            {
               IntelliChart iclass = new IntelliChart("test");
               Response.Write(iclass._chartName);
            }
         }
```